# My external JS file isn't loading

Tags: javascript, html

I followed Mozila's example on their web-site and tried to create a simple 2d game. Everything works fine. Then I decided to separate the code from the html page into a single js file. But for some unknown reason it isn't loaded into my html. 
here's my html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Gamedev Canvas Workshop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="Script.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the beginning of the script file:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 10;
var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height-30;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var paddleHeight = 10;
var paddleWidth = 75;
var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var brickRowCount = 5;
```

Again everything works fine when I use inline script inside the html. But as soon as I try to separate the code and html - it fails. Any help?

Comment: Do keep in mind that it is a bad idea to load external Javascript files in head tag. They should ideally be at the end of body tag. But that shouldn't be the reason for your issue.

Comment: @Nisarg yes it's the reason for the issue.

Comment: @baao: Well, the OP claims that inline scripts worked. If they were in the same place, they wouldn't.

Comment: Look at the browser's console to checkout any error messages.

Comment: Vlad - As Nisarg and baao pointed out, your `script` tag should be at the **end** of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag. That way, the canvas element exists and `getElementById` can find it. (Inline script would have the same problem.)

Comment: *"I followed Mozila's example on their web-site..."* Where is this example? (So that if it's on MDN, we can fix it.)

Comment: You are working on Linux or Mac?

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. I placed script tag at the bottom and it worked! Thank you for your help

Comment: @SaidbakR  I work on Windows